# Speak with burrowing animals

Tags: history-of-gaming

What was the first game system that canonically gave Gnomes the ability to talk to burrowing animals? I know D&D 3.5 had it, but was there something earlier?

Comment: I'm pretty sure this ability is specific to D&D (and possibly to games inspired by it), so I think this would be better tagged [tag:dungeons-and-dragons] rather than [tag:system-agnostic].

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Player Character Gnomes can speak with "any burrowing mammal (such as moles, badgers, ground squirrels, etc)" in first edition AD&D (PHB pg 16).  The blue book basic D&D (1974-78) does not have Gnomes as PCs, but does have Gnomes in the monster list, and makes no mention of them being able to speak wtih animals.